# R: Convert Brightkite location ID to place name

Tags: r, location

I've downloaded BrightKite data from SNAP for data mining purposes using R programming, each record of the dataset is in the form:

```
user    time                 lat           long                 locID
0   2010-10-17T01:48:53Z    39.747652   -104.99251 88c46bf20db295831bd2d1718ad7e6f5
```

My problem is that I want to know what place each location Id is corresponding to, isn't there any method by which I can parse Location IDs into places names?

Comment: You are after [geocoding](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158328/batch-geocoding-in-r).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik actually this is *reverse* geocoding - going from a lat-long to a readable place name. There's no info encoded in the locId, its just a random hex string corresponding to a place. Its possible BrightKite had a lookup at some point, but can't find that now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geonames API can get this. Install the latest version from github using devtools (install devtools from CRAN first if you haven't got it yet) and get yourself a geonames username from http://www.geonames.org/ :

```
> devtools::install_github("ropensci/geonames")
> require(geonames)
> options(geonamesUsername="sarashaker") # create a user at geonames.org
```

Then for some place with lat/long:

```
> place
       lat      long
1 39.74765 -104.9925
```

Call to `GNfindNearby` with a small radius parameter:

```
> res = GNfindNearby(lat=place$lat, lng=place$long,radius=0.1)
Warning message:
In GNfindNearby(lat = place$lat, lng = place$long, radius = 0.1) :
  Not documented properly yet by geonames
```

Ignore the warning - I don't think the response was well documented when I wrote this package. Anyway, the nearest match is the first element of the first element:

```
> closest = res[[1]][[1]]
> closest$name
[1] "Residence Inn by Marriott Denver City Center"
> closest$distance
[1] "0.01083"
```

The next closest place is the second element of the first element:

```
> res[[1]][[2]]$name
[1] "Hotel Monaco Denver - a Kimpton Hotel"
> res[[1]][[2]]$dist
[1] "0.01933"
```